# Using Thumbnailator, can i make thumbnail with same height and width regardless the image size

Tags: java, image-processing, thumbnails

In [Thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/), i am making thumbnails.

If image size is 400*300 and if i do following thing,

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("original.jpg"))
        .size(160, 160)
        .toFile(new File("thumbnail.jpg"));
```

it create thumbnail of 160*120.

What i want is if i upload 400*300 image, it will center zoom so that i will become 300*300 and then it will thumbnail.

I gone through the documentation, Even i posted same thing over there in comment but no luck.

Comment: I removed references to "google thumbnailator" as the Thumbnailator library is not affiliated with Google in any way. It is just a project which is hosted on Google Project Hosting.

Also, just to let you know, I didn't notice that you've posted a question on one of the Wiki documentation pages in the Thumbnailator project, as Google has recently turned off the update notification feature which could have brought this to my attention.

Comment: I am so glad to see this reply..! Right now i am doing BufferImage with getSubimage()...!
It worked but happy to have something inbuilt...! ;) 
really great library...! so easy to use...! :)

Comment: Glad that you found the library useful :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579004/using-thumbnailator-can-i-make-thumbnail-with-same-height-and-width-regardless

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [`sourceRegion`](https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.13/net/coobird/thumbnailator/Thumbnails.Builder.html#sourceRegion(net.coobird.thumbnailator.geometry.Position,%20int,%20int)) method which can be used to specify the region from which the thumbnail should be produced:

[image: Illustration of creating a thumbnail using the sourceRegion method in Thumbnailator]

In your particular case, you'll want to try the following:

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("original.jpg"))
  .sourceRegion(Positions.CENTER, 300, 300)
  .size(160, 160)
  .toFile(new File("thumbnail.jpg"));
```

The above code will:

1. Open the `original.jpg`,
2. Use the central 300 x 300 region of the original image, and
3. Resize that region to a 160 x 160 thumbnail, and
4. Writes to the `thumbnail.jpg`.

It's possible to select different regions of the original image by changing `Positions.CENTER` to, for example, `Positions.TOP_LEFT`. For a complete list of pre-defined choices, please look at the documentation for the [`Positions`](https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.13/net/coobird/thumbnailator/geometry/Positions.html) enum.

---

The following are some links to the Thumbnailator API documentation which may be of interest:

- [`sourceRegion(int, int, int, int)`](https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.13/net/coobird/thumbnailator/Thumbnails.Builder.html#sourceRegion(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method

  - Used to specify an exact region from which to create a thumbnail.
- [`sourceRegion(Position, int, int)`](https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.13/net/coobird/thumbnailator/Thumbnails.Builder.html#sourceRegion(net.coobird.thumbnailator.geometry.Position,%20int,%20int)) method

  - Uses relative positioning using the `Position` object as shown in the example code above.
- [`sourceRegion(Rectangle)`](https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.13/net/coobird/thumbnailator/Thumbnails.Builder.html#sourceRegion(java.awt.Rectangle)) method

  - Used to specify an exact region from which to create a thumbnail, using a [`java.awt.Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) object.
- [`Position`](https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.13/net/coobird/thumbnailator/geometry/Position.html) enum

  - Provides pre-defined positions which can be used to specify the relative position of the region from which to create a thumbnail.

---

*Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) library.*

Comment: @db80 Glad you found this useful :)