# Testing Thumbnailator in Play (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, integration-testing, playframework-2.4

I've been tasked with writing tests for [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator). These tests are geared to make sure that images uploaded are resized to `400x400` from the `CENTER` of the image (was able to find solution to image position from: [Using Thumbnailator, can i make thumbnail with same height and width regardless the image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579004/using-thumbnailator-can-i-make-thumbnail-with-same-height-and-width-regardless)).

I've seen unit tests in Scala before, but have not written anything to test a plugin. The plugin itself does not seem to have much documentation on how to test functionality. Is anyone smarter than myself able to provide me some guidance on how I would begin this?

Comment: I would say that you are not looking for a *unit test* but more like a component or integration test. Names apart, to test this image library, I would have some source (original images) and "hand made" thumbnails. After that, I would check the generated thumbnails against the "hand made" thumbnails to see they are similar. If so, the test passes, if not, the test fails. Of course, now you need a "image similarity" library. ;-)

Comment: Ah, another piece to the puzzle lol! You are right about the integration test, my bad, my brain isn't functioning the best today. Good approach though, thank you for the advice.